# Ignore overlaying element in context menu

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have element `#b` which partially covers element `#a` like this:

```
<style>
  div { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; }
  #a { left: 0; }
  #b { left: 100px; }
</style>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Now I would like to have a document-wide context menu:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", myhandler);
```

So `event.target` in `myhandler` contains the element on which I right-clicked. Is it possible to ignore `#b` and to bubble the event to the element below? (I need `#b` above all elements.)